# How to restore a database from large sql file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a 2 GB SQL file, generated from SQL Server database 2008, which includes data and schema. SQL Server 2008 Express does not even open the file saying an error:

> Error: HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

but, the file opens in word pad while it just hangs after loading the file.

Any idea or suggestions what is the problem and how to overcome?

Comment: Is the file delimited into batches? If so you could use `sqlcmd` or `osql`. If not I doubt these tools would work either as I doubt SQL Server Express could even parse a 2GB file with its 1GB memory limit.

Comment: @Martin hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue before, this is how I fixed it:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Change location
2. Change your location in the format tab to English (United States) and in the location tab change to United States.

Also please make sure that the `Language for non-Unicode program` section that you can find inside the `Administrative Tab` in the `Change Location` section should be set to English (United States).